# Get angle from matrix

Tags: javascript, math, actionscript, trigonometry

I know a matrix [x scale, y skew, x skew, y scale, trans x, trans y], and would like to get the angle in degrees.

thanks!

Comment: the center of the object being rotated, whose bounds will always be a rectangle

Comment: I should also add that the matrix may contain scale info it's not just straight rotation

Comment: Are you asking this: given a transformation matrix with scale and skew elements, how do you work out the equivalent angle of rotation?

Comment: Yes an angle from a transform matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following matrix

```
| x_sc  y_sk  0  |
| x_sk  y_sc  0  |
| x_tr  y_tr  1  |
```

with `sk` indicating skew, `sc` indicating scale and `tr` indicating translation.

This only represents a **pure** rotation if all three are true

```
y_sk == -x_sk
y_sc == x_sc
x_sc * y_sc - x_sk * y_sk == 1
```

In this case, if `theta` is the angle of rotation, then

```
theta == arcos(x_sc)
```

This will give you the answer in radians (most likely), so you'll need to convert to degrees.

Assuming you have an object called M, representing the matrix, the properties that match my definitions above, you could do:

```
function toPureRotation(var M) {
    if( (M.y_sk != (-1 * M.x_sk)) ||
        (M.y_sc != M.x_sc) ||
        ((M.x_sc * M.y_sc - M.x_sk * M.y_sk) != 1)
    ) {
        return Number.NaN;
    }
    else {
        return Math.acos(M.x_sc); // For radians
        return Math.acos(M.x_sc) * 180 / Math.PI; // For degrees
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

For a pure rotation followed by (or preceded by) a scaling transform that maintains aspect ratio:

```
| sc   0  0 |
|  0  sc  0 |
|  0   0  1 |
```

Then you can us the following identity:

```
x_sc * y_sc - x_sk * y_sk == sc^2
```

This gives us

```
function toRotation(var M) {
    if( (M.y_sk != (-1 * M.x_sk)) ||
        (M.y_sc != M.x_sc)
      )
    ) {
        return Number.NaN;
    }
    else {
        var scale_factor = Math.sqrt((M.x_sc * M.y_sc - M.x_sk * M.y_sk));
        return Math.acos(M.x_sc/scale_factor); // For radians
        return Math.acos(M.x_sc/scale_factor) * 180 / Math.PI; // For degrees
    }
}
```

If you want to factor in translations, you're entering a world of hurt.

Comment: That's the right answer for pure rotation but the object may have also been scaled.

Comment: "you're entering a world of hurt" that made me laugh, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 8):

very simple

1: get matrix and save in variable

```
matrix='matrix(0.8660254037844387, 0.49999999999999994, -0.49999999999999994, 0.8660254037844387, 0, 0)';
```

2: split value

```
var values = matrix.split('(')[1],
    values = values.split(')')[0],
    values = values.split(',');

var sin = values[1]; // 0.5
```

3: calc angle

```
var angle = Math.round(Math.asin(sin) * (180/Math.PI));
```

result:

```
function convertToAngle(matrix) {
     var values = matrix.split('(')[1],
        values = values.split(')')[0],
        values = values.split(',');

    var sin = values[1]; // 0.5

    return Math.round(Math.asin(sin) * (180/Math.PI));
}
```

Comment: Simple and efficient! :)

Comment: all i needed was this formula (`Math.round(Math.asin(sin) * (180/Math.PI))`) and it works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

I'm just gonna place this here for future reference. I went ahead and created a quick jQuery method that attempts to calculate the angle of rotation of a given HTML element. Hopefully, this will save someone the trouble I had.

https://gist.github.com/1492454