# css transform. How to get rotation degree value from "matrix( 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0")?

Tags: css, math, matrix

How to convert this matrix into degrees?

I'm rotating a `div` with  `transform: rotate()`. And I want to get the rotation value.

When I try  `$( icon ).css('transform')`, it returns a matrix value like `matrix(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)`.

My question is how do I convert the matrix value into degree value?

This is what I've found:

```
0°     matrix(  0,  0,   0,  0, 0, 0)
45°    matrix( .7, .7, -.7, .7, 0, 0)
90°    matrix(  0,  1,  -1,  0, 0, 0)
180°   matrix( -1,  0,   0, -1, 0, 0)
270°   matrix(  0, -1,   1,  0, 0, 0)
```

Sorry if this is more of a math question...

Comment: This is similar to this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072271/get-angle-from-matrix, hope this helps.

Comment: Use plain javascript, that will give you the value you're looking for without creating a matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without being a mathematician, you can parse the rotation angle from the style.

```
var style = $(el).attr('style'),
    rotation = parseInt(style.substr(style.indexOf("rotate("+7));
```

Note: This works because jQuery modifies the style attribute. If you set the rotation in CSS initially, it won't work.